# STSADM or C# script to delete all custom site templates

Tags: 2007, development, stsadm

I want to delete Custom site templates off my farm and wondering if someone know any script I can use.

Not a big fan of Powershell at the moment as I am using SharePoint 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [stsadm](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263068%28v=office.12%29.aspx) `deletetemplate`

```
stsadm -o deletetemplate

   -title <template title>

   [-lcid] <language>
```

Sample Usage: `stsadm –o  deletetemplate –title YourTemplateName`

Peform an iisreset afterwards to ensure removal.